# problem with setDateFormat for my iPad app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I use the following to get the date.

```
NSDate *today =[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//manage day of week and date.
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
dayOfWeek = [formatter stringFromDate:today];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
theDate = [formatter stringFromDate:today];

// manage the time and am/pm
[formatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm"];
theTime = [formatter stringFromDate:today];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"a"];
amPM = [[formatter stringFromDate:today] retain];

[formatter release];
```

My app crashes if I use `[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM"]`. Do I need to convert the integer to string ? Is so please correct my code on how to get the current date

Comment: Please post the code that craches your app and the console output.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM"];
NSString *theDate = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
```

**setDateFormat** doesn't return anything, stringFromDate returns what you are looking for.

And don't retain like you did in this line:

```
amPM = [[formatter stringFromDate:today] retain];
```

The formatter has already a retain count of 1 by using alloc.

Comment: Ah I see, i corrected my answer. You have to do it in two steps :)

Comment: Nick, see my code above.. I have done the same thing..Any other alternatives?

Comment: Please look at the code you've posted carefully: You are assigning something theDate, but the method you are invoking on the right side isn't right. You are calling setDateFormat, which should be called first as a separate first step: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"d MMM"];
` Then assign: `NSString *theDate = [formatter stringFromDate:today];`